# Rspec on RoR; passing parameters in JSON format (params are empty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The problem here when I passed JSON parameters with Rspec(request type),
parameters are not correctly passed to the controller. (On the real world, it's working.)

Any ideas?

`controllers/api/v1/subscriptions_controller.rb`

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
      # TODO: Better user inheritance

      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token # Disable CSRF to enable to function as API
      before_action :restrict_content_type
      before_action :restrict_accept_header
      before_action :load_plans

      respond_to :json

      # NOTE: This block is used when you put unrelated values
      rescue_from(ArgumentError) do |e|
        render json: { error: e.message }, states: :bad_request
      end

      rescue_from(ActionController::ParameterMissing) do |e|
        error = {}
        error[e.param] = ['parameter is required']
        response = { errors: [error] }
        render json: response, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end


      def create
       binding.pry #<= `params` is empty within Testing.
      end

      private

      def restrict_content_type
        render json: { msg: 'Content-Type must be application/json' }, status: 406 unless request.content_type == 'application/json'
      end

      def restrict_accept_header
        render json: { msg: 'Accept-Header must be application/json' }, status: 406 unless request.headers['Accept'] =~ /json/
      end

      def load_plans
        @plans = Plan.where(published: true).order('amount')
      end

      def foo_params
        params.require(:foo)
      end


      # NOTE: returns validation errors with JSON API format
      def jsonapi_errors(model)
        errors = []
        model.errors.messages.each do |attr, message|
          errors.push(title: 'Invalid Attribute', detail: "#{attr.capitalize}: #{message[0]}")
        end
        errors
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`spec/requests/subscription_request.spec`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::SubscriptionsController, type: :request do
  describe 'General API test' do

    before(:each) do
      host! 'api.lvh.me'
    end

    let(:headers) do
    {
      'ACCEPT' => 'application/json',     # This is what Rails 4 accepts
      'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
    }
  end
let(:json_body) do
  {format: :json, foo: 'test'} # Invalid request
end



   it 'returns 200 to valid json' do

      post '/subscriptions', json_body, headers
      binding.pry
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your params as below and try it?

> let(:headers) { { "ACCEPT" => "application/json", "CONTENT_TYPE" =>
>   "application/json" } }   let(:json_body) { {format: :json, foo:
>   'test'}}

Check routes too.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However this doesn't work; syntax error occurs.